# Rails 5 - Helper methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

I am trying to learn how to use helper methods in my Rails 5 app.

I have a model called `Proposal` and another called `User`.

In my `Proposal` helper, I'm trying to write a helper to show the name and location of the parent user (proposals belong to users).

I have tried:

```
def text_for_proponent(proposal, user)
  return unless current_user.id == proposal.user.id
    render 'users/profiles/formal_name_title', user: @proposal.user
end
```

Then in my views/users/formal_name_title.html.erb, I have:

```
<%= @user.full_name.titleize %> · <%= @user.organisation.title.titleize %> · <%#= @user.addresses.first.country_name.titleize %>
```

Then in my proposals/show.html.erb, I have:

```
<h4><%= text_for_proponent(@proposal, @proposal.user) %></h4>
```

This isn't working. I can't find how to give the user instance to the helper to be used in populating the view.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Did my answer help you resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to access `@proposal.user` but `@proposal` is `nil` inside the helper. You should use the local variable `proposal` instead.

```
render 'users/profiles/formal_name_title', user: proposal.user
```

And, you should change your partial to use the local variable `user`.

```
<%= user.full_name.titleize %> · <%= user.organisation.title.titleize %> · <%= user.addresses.first.country_name.titleize %>
```

Comment: Thank you Arun - I really appreciate your help